# Synonym for "get affected by" in academic form?

Tags: writing, academia, tech-writing

I am writing a paper and I have some measurements and factors which change according to the change of some others. I have already used several times "A affects B". Therefore, I need to use a different way of expressing this phrase, like "B gets affected by A". I would be grateful if you gave me some examples.

Comment: I'd say ***get*** is probably too informal for your context - use *A **is** affected by B*.

Comment: I would suggest that when you are describing something scientific, you don't need to avoid repetition in your language:  the ultimate aim is clarity, here, not creating beautiful prose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider "A [influences](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/influence) B" as an alternative to "B gets affected by A".

"Get" is a bit of a short and ugly word but it does get the job done, and as @Max suggests you should not be changing terms willy-nilly just to make it more readable. In technical writing, as in people, accuracy and consistency should be a higher priority than beauty.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I also gained some idea which might help other readers as well. "B is subject to changes of A" or "B is a function of A" are also good replacements. please correct me if I'm wrong.